# Adding a GPS receiver to java code?

Tags: java, android, location, maps

I am experimenting with building a location based app and have entered the following code below but When I run the app it moves location to where my phone is and brings up lots of other GPS phones that are in the same location.I need to be able to just see my location.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import android.location.Location;


import android.widget.Toast;


import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends Activity {

    private GoogleMap map;

    private static final LatLng LONDON =
            new LatLng(+51.50000, -0.11670);

    private LocationManager lm;
    private LocationListener locationListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                .newLatLngZoom(LONDON, 15));
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(LONDON));


        lm = (LocationManager)
                getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationListener = new MyLocationListener();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);



    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        lm.removeUpdates(locationListener);

    }

    private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {






        @Override

        public void onLocationChanged(Location location){
            if (location!= null){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        "Location changed:" + location.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                LatLng latLng = new

                        LatLng(location.getLatitude(),
                        location.getLongitude());
                map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,15));

                map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng));
                            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Theres no way you are getting the location of other phones around you. You just receive fixes from your phone's GPS chip.

What happens is that on each location received you are adding a new marker, but you are not clearing the previously added markers.

Answer (score 0):

Before adding new marker you need to remove the old one. When you adding marker, you can simply instantiate it to a variable like this:

```
Marker marker = map.addMarker(..);
```

and then remove it like this:

```
 marker.remove();
```

***EDIT**

Notice, that GPS sensors in smartphones are really inaccurate, so received position from this kind of sensor will "jump" around your actual position. It could be really far from you (hundreds of meters), it depends on whether, satellite positions and your sensor calibration. You have almost no chance to get position with accuracy lower then 5 meters.